# ShinyDashboard: Switching between default theme and dark mode

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I used [this](https://github.com/nik01010/dashboardThemeSwitcher) tutorial to introduce dark mode switcher to my app.
I would like the app to come back to the default theme when checkbox not checked.
I can't find a "default" theme in dashboardthemes library nor default theme definition to be used in shinyDashboardThemeDIY() function.
Any clue will be much appreciated.

Below a reproducible piece of code (it works perfectly in a first stage, but nothing happens when I uncheck the checkbox: theme remain dark instead of becoming white and blue again)

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dashboardthemes)

# Functions
uiDarkModeCheckBox <- function()
{
    ns <- NS("moduleChangeTheme")
    checkbox <- tagList(
        checkboxInput(
            inputId = ns("dbxChangeTheme"),
            label = "Dark Mode",
            value = FALSE
        )
    )
    
    return(checkbox)
}

uiChangeThemeOutput <- function()
{
    ns <- NS("moduleChangeTheme")
    themeOutput <- tagList(
        uiOutput(ns("uiChangeTheme"))
    )
    
    return(themeOutput)
}

serverChangeTheme <- function(input, output, session)
{
    observeEvent(
        input$dbxChangeTheme, 
        {
            output$uiChangeTheme <- renderUI({
                if (input$dbxChangeTheme == TRUE) {
                    uiChangeThemeOutput()
                    shinyDashboardThemes(theme = "grey_dark")
                }
            })
        }
    )
}

# UI
ui <- dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(),
                    dashboardSidebar(),
                    dashboardBody(
                        uiChangeThemeOutput(),
                            tabItem(tabName = "inputs_tab",
                                    uiDarkModeCheckBox(),
                            )
                    )

)

# SERVER
server <- function(input, output, session) {

    callModule(module = serverChangeTheme, id = "moduleChangeTheme")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Please provide us with some reproducible code that you have tried so far.

Comment: A reproducible piece of code has been added

Answer (score 1):

Set the default theme according to your need `defaultTheme = "grey_light"`.

```
 uiChangeThemeDropdown <- function(dropDownLabel = "Change Theme", defaultTheme = "grey_light")
  {
    changeThemeChoices <- c(
      "Blue gradient" = "blue_gradient",
      "Flat Red" = "flat_red",
      "Grey light" = "grey_light",
      "Grey dark" = "grey_dark",
      "OneNote" = "onenote",
      "Poor man's Flatly" = "poor_mans_flatly",
      "Purple gradient" = "purple_gradient"
    )
```

Comment: This does not fix my issue. "grey_light" is not the shiny default theme. I am looking for a way to enable switching themes between the default theme and "grey_dark" theme so that the user could switch it multiple times within one run of the shiny app (see a reproducible piece of code I've posted above). Thank you!